# FluentWait doesn't wait by elementToBeClickable() method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, wait

I use following code to wait while page is loaded.

```
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(40, SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(10, SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(webelements.labelForInputFileField)));
    log.info("Page loaded!");
```

It doesn't work, I get following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:787)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:96)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:87)

I tried with `presenceOfElementLocated()` method too, but same error. Requested page is loaded, I see it visually in browser.

Comment: IMO, you have mixed up `FluentWait` and `WebDriverWait`. Can you update us your exact manual steps which you are trying to Automate along with the relevant HTML?

Comment: There is a file chooser, which should be clicked after page is loaded. It seems, it doesn't wait until page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below `FluentWait` code :-

```
WebElement waitsss(WebDriver driver, By elementIdentifier){
     Wait<WebDriver> wait =
                new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        return wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
                {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                           return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier);
                    }
                });
}
```

if still not work. check your XPath. It may be your XPATH is invalid and so `FluentWait` throw expection

Another thing is that `FluentWait`and `Explicit wait` are two different type of waits. You can't mix with another

For Explicit wait use below code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(ad, 100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gst")).sendKeys(username);
```

refer below:-

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/

OR Use `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement Searchelement=driver.findElement("Your locator");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Searchelement);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Not working for me, has the same effect. Xpath should be ok, because I used it earlier with `WebDriverWait` in version 2.53.1. I just try to update my testcase to 3.5.

Comment: I have added a code of JavascriptExecutor to click element.. try it

Comment: Same effect with this code too, NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

1. `java.lang.NullPointerException` - This exception usually indicates that smthn is null, make sure that variables driver and webelements are set by the time you're executing this method.
2. Make sure you're not using Guava version that is not compatible with your current framework

Comment: Please check my question.